# How to make x is a whole number a condition in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a decimal to binary to octal to hexadecimal to base 20 (I added up to base 36 functionality) calculator for school. It works and catches a few exceptions, except it does something weird when a decimal (like 4.5, not the number system) value is input. I want it to just catch it and take the user back to the top of my code and say "please try again and input a whole number", I'm thinking I should use an if statement to do that and I just need to know how to make "x is a whole number" a condition. I'm using Java by the way.

This is the part of my code I'm working on:

```
public class mainconvert //creates my main class

{ //start mainconvert

    public static int manualparse(String m)//initializes an int method for a manual parse instead of using the library
    {//start manualparse

        int parsedvalue = 0;//creates an int that the parsed value will go into
        char[] split = m.toCharArray();//takes the input and splits it into an array of characters so we can take each individual character and convert it to an int
        int n = 0;//creates an int that will be used for the power that 10 is raised to while converting the input place

        for(int o=m.length()-1; o>=0; o--)//creates a for loop that takes each place in the array and loops through the conversion process until every place is converted
        {//start conversion for
            parsedvalue += Math.pow(10,n)*(split[o]-'0');//does the math, takes the char in each place, gets its ascii value, subtracts ascii 0 from that and multiplies it by 10^n, seen previously
            n++;//increases n (the exponent) by 1 after each loop to match the place that is being worked on
        }//end conversion for

        return parsedvalue;//returns the final parsed value
    }//end manualparse

    public static void main(String args[])//creates the main entry point
    {//start main

        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();//makes JOptionPane "pane" so I don't have to type out "JOptionPane"

        boolean binput = false;

        do{//start do for do while loop for the reset on the exception catcher

            try{//start try for exception catcher

                String input = pane.showInputDialog("Enter value for conversion");//makes a Jpane with an input box for the value to be converted
                StringTokenizer toke = new StringTokenizer(input);//makes a string tokenizer for the input
                String k = toke.nextToken();//uses toke.nextToken to grab the token put into the input box so it can be used, it is made into a string
                int x = manualparse(k);//uses the manual parsing method created earlier to parse the token grabbed in string k into an int for use in our conversions

// then a bunch of calculator stuff and here's the end of the try/catch and do while loop

}//end try for exception catcher

catch(Exception ex)//catches exception

{//start catch

binput = true;//changes boolean to true to trigger do while loop

pane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again and input an integer");//displays error

}//end catch

}while(binput==true);//while for do while loop, triggers while the boolean binput is true
```

Comment: Show us some code, what are the types of the variables you're using ?

Comment: Learn about Exception Handling. Google it. The first link will take you to Oracle Tutorial. Yes, that is the place where you can start.

Comment: Show us (part of) your code. How are you reading the number? What exactly does "it does something weird" mean? To get good help, you need to explain the problem as precisely as possible.

Comment: The thing is that it doesn't throw an exception, it just does the conversion based on the calculator I built because it is an int, it's just not the kind of int I want.

Answer (score 2):

The user enters the input in a string form. Just check if that string is formatted correctly.

```
boolean valid;
int input;
String inputString = ...;
try
{
    input = Integer.parseInt(inputString, 36);
    valid = true;
} catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    valid = false;
    input = 0;
}
```

Or a more intuitive solutions:

```
boolean valid = inputString.matches("(+|-)?[0-9a-zA-Z]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt() is restricted to parsing a number within the int range, so it may be too restrictive if you are handling larger numbers. There is the corresponding Long.parseLong(), but for arbitrarily large numbers, use this:

```
try {
    new BigInteger(input, 36); // or whatever base
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // bad input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you do

```
parsedvalue += Math.pow(10,n)*(split[o]-'0');
```

without validating that `split[o]` is a number.  It could be any character, even a `.` ;)

You need to validate the text because doing `- '0'` will not throw an exception regardless of what you subtract it from, nor would you expect it to.

BTW: It's very expensive to create object or use pow to parse a number.  You should try to avoid both.

Here is an example which handles negative numbers, different bases, validating characters but doesn't create objects or use Math.pow.

```
public static long parseLong(String s, int base) {
    boolean negative = false;
    long num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        int value = Character.getNumericValue(ch);
        if (value >= 0 && value < base)
            num = num * base + value;
        else
            throw new NumberFormatException("Unexpect character '" + ch + "' for base " + base);
    }
    return negative ? -num : num;
}
```